# Asp.Net Core Project Combine Web and Windows Service

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Is it possible to have a service API that can handle API request / responses, but also have an internal service running on a timer. e.g Every 2 hours check database Logs and delete info logs, something like that?

Comment: IHostedService might suite you.

Answer (score 0):

Asp.Net Core is like any other .NET Core application, it has a Main function where you can start all non-blocking operations you want.

In Program.cs:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Here you can start your timer (maybe using a dedicated class)
    //Just avoid blocking code...

    //Starting Asp.Net Core web host.
    BuildWebHost(args).Run();
}
```

If you find more confortable, you can do the same inside Configure/ConfigureServices methods in your Startup.cs file, hopefully creating a specific service for your purpose.